# I get an error when I try to include the script in another directory : Why is that?

Tags: php, namespaces

The following script is inside the directory named `package_1` :

```
<?php
namespace ashaar;
class Ghazal {
    public function nameIt() {
        echo "Dekh to dil ke jaan se utha hai <br />";
    }
}
```

and the following script is inside the directory named `package_2` :

```
<?php
namespace package_1\ashaar;
require 'first.php';
$obj = new Ghazal();
$obj->nameIt();
```

When I run the above script *(inside the directory package 2 )* I get an error :

```
Warning: require(\package_1\first.php): failed to open stream: No such file 
or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/package_2/second.php on line 3

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '\package_1\first.php'
(include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/package_2/second.php
 on line 3
```

Why is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*first.php*

```
<?php
namespace ashaar;
class Ghazal {
    public function nameIt() {
        echo "Dekh to dil ke jaan se utha hai <br />";
    }
}
```

*second.php*

```
<?php
namespace ashaar;
require_once('../package_1/first.php');
$obj = new Ghazal();
$obj->nameIt();
```

What made you do `package_1\ashaar` when you are including `first.php` that is inside the package `package_1`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the location to:

```
require '..\package_1\first.php';
```

Comment: then your folder structure is not what you have stated. screenshot of the folder tree?

Comment: http://i49.tinypic.com/25ui3ac.png

Answer (score 0):

change the location as

```
include_once("..\package_1\first.php");
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you must use namespaces like that.

first.php...

```
<?php
namespace package_1\ashaar;
class Ghazal {
    public function nameIt() {
        echo "Dekh to dil ke jaan se utha hai <br />";
    }
}
```

second.php...

```
<?php

namespace package_2;
require '../package_1/first.php';
use package_1\ashaar\Ghazal;


$obj = new Ghazal();
$obj->nameIt();
```

See `use` keyword which is essential to use code in another namespace.

Comment: I made changes, now it works. Change use keyword to embed Ghazal also.

Comment: Well down-vote is ok. But at least comment should be given, So answers can be improved.